# How to stop Celery task callbacks?

Tags: python, celery

I have a 3 celery tasks like this:

```
@app.task
def main_func():
    if this:
        func1.delay()
    else:
        func2.delay()

@app.task
def func1():
    ... do something ...

@app.task
def func2():
    ... do something ...
```

Function `main_func` is scheduled to execute every 30 secs. If some condition is fulfilled then it calls a celery task of `func1` else creates a task for `func2`.

Now when i run the celery worker and the function `main_func` is executed then it calls itself again with `func1` or `func2` resulting in looping.

Now in log the tasks should have a time difference of 30 seconds between consecutive executions but because of looping they keeps on executing one after another.

How can I prevent this situation?

Note: I am using celery 4.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
celery.current_app.send_task('mymodel.tasks.mytask', args=[arg1, arg2, arg3])
```

where `current_app` is property of celery module. `mymodel.task`s is a path to your `tasks.py`